# Segmentation fault on linux-working on windows

Tags: c, linux, gcc, segmentation-fault

The goal of this program is to scan a string populated with numbers and white spaces between them and insert each number into an array. Then each number from the array is sent to `checkPowerOfTwo` function which determines if the number sent is a power of two and prints the calculation.

When I run this program on windows everything is workingfine. Running on Linux causes a segmentation fault.

I'm compiling my code on a Linux server with : `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -DNDEBUG main.c -o mtm_tot`. It compiles successfully with no errors or warnings. The problem arises when I try to run a tester : `./mtm_tot< test1.in > tmpout`. After pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> on this line `Segmentation fault` rises.

```
test1.in contains : 8

5 9 -1 4 20 256 -32 17 32
```

The code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int checkPowerOfTwo(int x);
int main()
{
    int exp,size,sum=0,*numbers;
    char term,*str=NULL,*token;

    printf("Enter size of input:\n");
    if(scanf("%d%c", &size, &term) != 2 || term != '\n'){
        printf("Invalid Size\n");
        return 0;
    } if(size<=0){
        printf("Invalid size\n");
        return 0;
    } else{
        numbers=(int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(size+1) + (size-1)*sizeof(char));
        if(numbers==NULL||str==NULL){
            printf("Out of memory\n");
            return 0;
        } //else{
        //printf("Memory allocated\n");
        //}
        printf("Enter numbers:");
        fgets (str, sizeof(int)*(size+1) + (size-1), stdin);
        //printf("%s",str);
        token=strtok(str," ");
        while(token!=NULL){
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                //printf("token is %s\n",token);
                //numbers[i]=token;
                sscanf(token,"%d",&numbers[i]);
                //printf("Inserting %s to the array\n ",numbers[i]);
                token=strtok(NULL," ");
            }
        }
    }

    for(int j =0;j<size;j++)
    {
        //sscanf(numbers[j],"%d",&x);
        //printf("the number im sending is : %d ",x);
        exp=checkPowerOfTwo(numbers[j]);
        if (exp>=0){
            printf("The number %d is a power of 2: %d=2^%d\n",numbers[j],numbers[j],exp);
            sum+=exp;
        }
    }
    printf("Total exponent sum is %d",sum);
    free(numbers);
    free(str);
}

int checkPowerOfTwo(int x)
{
    int exponent=0;
    //sscanf(n,"%d",&x);
    //printf("checking number %d\n",x);
    if (x==0){
        return -1;
    } if  (x==1){
        return 0;
    }
    while( x != 1)
    {
        if(x % 2 != 0){
            return -1;
        }
        x /= 2;
        exponent++;
    }
    return exponent;
}
```

Comment: Does your program provide any output prior to the segmentation fault? I would also consider printing your errors to stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: Because `size` and `numbers` are uninitialized, if you have an invalid size, you will dereference a NULL pointer in `numbers` when you try and check for powers of two (at the bottom of `main`). The `malloc` for `numbers` never is executed.

Comment: It's a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: By the way sizeof(int) has nothing to do with reading strings and scanning integers. `sizeof(int)*(size+1) + ...` makes no sense. Your method of parsing input is overcomplicated and there is absolutely no need to go to such lengths just to read a bunch of number. `scanf("%d", &num)` in a loop would work perfectly fine.

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) Use the dereferenced pointer to set the *type-size* (e.g. `numbers = malloc (size * sizeof *numbers);`) and  you will never get the *type-size* wrong. `sizeof(char);` is always `1` and should be omitted. `scanf ("%d%c"...` is horribly fragile, instead just remove any chars that remain in `stdin` with a loop over `getchar();` while the character isn't `'\n'` or `EOF`. S p a c e  Y o u r C o d e....

Comment: Given that `str` is a char pointer, the line `str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(size+1) + (size-1)*sizeof(char));` should cause all kinds of alarms to go off in your head :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the input file `test1.in` as shown in the question you specify a size of 8 and provide 9 numbers.

Your code

```
        while(token!=NULL){
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                //printf("token is %s\n",token);
                //numbers[i]=token;
                sscanf(token,"%d",&numbers[i]);
                //printf("Inserting %s to the array\n ",numbers[i]);
                token=strtok(NULL," ");
            }
        }
```

will enter the outer `while` loop and process 8 numbers in the first run of the inner `for` loop.
As you have entered 9 numbers, `token` will not be `NULL` and the outer loop will repeat and run the inner loop again. This will partially overwrite the numbers in the array. After processing the 9th number in the first cycle, `token` will become `NULL` and in the 2nd cycle `sscanf` will try to use the `NULL` pointer which may lead to a segmentation fault.

You should combine the counter and the check for `NULL` in the loop condition.
I also recommend to check the return value of `sscanf` because a value `!= 1` will indicate invalid input.

```
        for(int i=0; (i<size) && (token!=NULL); i++) {
            if(sscanf(token,"%d",&numbers[i]) != 1) {
                /* invalid input */
                break;
            }
            token=strtok(NULL," ");
        }
```

Of course the code following the loop must handle the case that the loop ends with `i < size` if not enough values were present.

**Edit:** additional clarification below

Note: The error checking for `scanf` is incomplete. It will return `0` if it couldn't convert an integer number, but it will also return `1` if it converted an integer number and anything is following it, e.g. for `123abc` it will convert `123` and return `1`. To check what may follow the number you could add a `%c` conversion and if the return values is `2` check the converted character. (`'\n'` or `'\r'` may be OK here.)

I would prefer to use `strtol` in a loop to parse the numbers in `str`.

BTW: The size calculation for the allocation of `str` is wrong. `sizeof int` is the size of the internal binary representation of an `int` value which is 4 (4 bytes = 32 bits) on many systems. It has nothing to do with how many characters are needed for a string representation of a number. A valid number `-2147483648` needs 11 characters.

(You could use a buffer `str` that is too small for the whole line but big enough for more than a valid number if you move the remaining data to the beginning and append new data after pasing a number until you have read the terminating newline.)

Comment: That fixed the segmentation error. 
The sscanf line you wrote should be False whenever a non integer type is inside token ?

Comment: Good job combining the `while (token != NULL) {` and `for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {` conditionals. A one-too-few, or one-too-many on input would almost guarantee a SegFault otherwise.

Comment: @eliranT see my clarification added to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your program logic is wrong:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sscanf(token, "%d", &numbers[i]);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");

    // token may become NULL here
    // and sscanf will segfault right after
  }
```

There may be other problems though.